# Инкапсуляция в Javascript

Tags: javascript

Допустим у меня есть объект:

```
obj = {
dataOne: "foo",
dataTwo: "foo"
};
```

Как правильно инкапсулировать `dataOne` и `dataTwo`, чтоб другие не смогли изменить значение?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Кого вы понимаете под "другими"? Если вы хотите, чтобы эти поля могли изменять только методы объекта obj, то можно сделать их локальными переменными внутри конструирующей функции:

```
function createObj() {
   var data = "foo";
   return {
      getData: function() {
        return data;
      }
   };
}
```

**UPD**: даже лучше использовать setter/getter. Так для вызывающей стороны поле будет выглядеть как обычный property:

```
function createObj() {
   var data = "foo";
   return Object.freeze({
      get data() {
        return data;
      },
      set data(ignored) {
        throw "'data' set is not allowed";
      }
   });
};
var o = createObj();
console.log(o.data); // OK
o.data = "1234"; // Exception
```

**UPD2**: я обернул возвращаемый объект в Object.freeze, чтобы защититься от Object.defineProperty. Правда я не знаю как защититься от подмены Object.freeze.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, под другими я понимаю что поля можно легко изменить через консоль javascript в браузере и присвоить полям любое значение.

Comment: Тип обходится всё, даже window.navigator, который по идее readOnly ^^

    Object.defineProperty(o, 'data', {
 get: function() { return data; },
 set: function(value) { data = value; } 
    });

Comment: @lampa, не работает почему-то (node.js):
> o.data
ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at Object.data (repl:2:26)
    at repl:1:3
    at REPLServer.eval (repl.js:80:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:182:12)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:162:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:426:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:603:14)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (readline.js:82:12)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:88:20)